# Get boolean from private void to a String class

Tags: c#, string, boolean

Having trouble communicating from a private void to a String class. Code is as follows:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
  bool host = false;
  string HostName = "";
  string HostName1 = "192.168.0.30";
  string HostName2 = "192.168.0.31";

  String SendCommand(String Command)
  {
    if (host == false)
       HostName = HostName1;
    else if (host == true)
       HostName = HostName2;
    //code that uses Hostname to toggle switch, which does work
   }

  private void btnProgramEther_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    host = true;
    SendCommand("turn switch on");
  }
}
```

With the code above, setting host to true does not change it in String SendCommand (String Command). When I do this...

```
String SendCommand(String Command)
  {
    host = true;
    if (host == false)
       HostName = HostName1;
    else if (host == true)
       HostName = HostName2;
    //code that uses Hostname to toggle switch, which does work
   }
```

...it does see the change and works fine. I tried changed the button to public void, and the string class to public String SendCommand, but that did not work. I also put the button click code before the String class, but that also did not work. I'm not sure what to do since the SendCommand("turn switch on");   does turn the switch on for HostName1, but not HostName2, since it doesn't see the boolean change.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the debugger, set a breakpoint in `btnProgramEther_Click_1` and then step into the call to `SendCommand`.

Comment: What you're suggesting isn't possible with the code you've presented, I don't think anyone would be able to reproduce this behaviour (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jVqE8k), for example - it works!). Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @CharlesMager  The problem is that I have 2 relay boards connected to my computer that I am using c# to turn the relays on and off, that's why I have 2 different IP addresses. I'm using the boolean host to toggle between which board I am communicating with.

Comment: @Canucksctr7 Your stated problem doesn't relate to those though, just to how you're updating the value of a variable in one function and using it in another.

Comment: @Canucksctr7 that's not relevant to your problem. As I've tried to show, the code you've given us doesn't behave in the way you claim it does. It's not really possible to help fix a problem until you can demonstrate it.

Comment: I don't really understand what your issue is. Based on the code in the SendCommand() method you're toggling which host to send the command to. The host can be a parameter to the method, instead of using a bool member variable.

Comment: @Mangist The problem is that the code the OP has posted should work fine with the bool variable, and the question revolves around the claim that it doesn't.  Yes there might be better/different ways to right this, but that's not what's being asked.

Comment: Yes the code should work fine but its hardly maintainable, but no harm in helping him write better code. If there's a better way of doing it, it should be pointed out. That's all I'm saying. @JamesThorpe

Comment: @Mangist Indeed.  But if the code that has been posted looks like it doesn't behave in the way the OP described it as behaving, changing it to something else entirely might hide a broken behaviour further.  We need to figure out why what's there isn't working first before making it better - and based on the code & description posted, we can't do that.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the way he's writing code, that app will always be bug prone and difficult to maintain. There isn't enough code posted above to work out exactly what the problem is. On top of that, that SendCommand() should be burned, its just awful.

Comment: @Mangist _"There isn't enough code posted above to work out exactly what the problem is."_ - that's exactly what I'm saying, and why there's (currently) 2 close votes for that specific reason.

Comment: I'm using the SendCommand() becaues I'm using a connection to TeraTerm to communicate with the relay boards. I'm not sure how to re-write the code to make it easier for you lads, sorry. But I'll try to use your suggestion @Mangist as I do believe it will work, it'll just be a longer change for me.

Comment: @Canucksctr7 there's no 'rewriting to make it easier' required.  The code you have in the question *actually works the way you want it to*.  You must see that makes it impossible to tell you how to 'fix' it?

Comment: @CharlesMager oh my bad, I didn't realize it worked for you guys. I don't want to post too much code as I don't think most of it pertains to the situation. Thanks for the help, and I'll look into this a bit further, and hopefully post something in a bit

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the hostname to your SendCommand() method?

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    private const string HOST_1 = "192.168.0.30";
    private const string HOST_2 = "192.168.0.31";

    private string SendCommand(string host, string Command)
    {
        //code that uses Hostname to toggle switch, which does work
        // Just use host here
    }

    private void btnProgramEther_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendCommand(HOST_1, "turn switch on");
    }
}
```